# How to find missing data using interpolation method

Tags: python

I have a question about the numerical method, which is used to find Calculating water consumption volume and cost.

*I have the following flow speed datasheet.*
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1akC9YkCNEHHHAunEr6TYJ88Ps_osbCianbH-wiZXSrM/edit?usp=sharing

The data taken above is Flow Speed.
before the data is converted to flow rate, there is data that is minus, which means the data is zero or it is assumed that the data taken is damaged. before the data is converted to flow rate, there is data that is minus, which means the data is zero or it is assumed that the data taken is damaged. I was asked to find the missing data using the interpolation method.

In your opinion, what interpolation method is suitable to get that value?

for the code, I've been looking for the results, but the missing value has not been found.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import babel.numbers
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv("log_level_out_mini.csv",delimiter=',')
data.set_index('eTime')

data.describe()

data['eTime']= pd.to_datetime(data['eTime'])
data.dtypes

data.plot(x = 'eTime', y = 'eValue')

data['eValue'][data['eValue']<0] = 0
data
```

results.

```
    eTime                         eValue
  0 2017-07-16 00:00:50.017       0.000
  1 2017-07-16 00:01:50.017       0.000
  2 2017-07-16 00:02:50.020       0.000
  3 2017-07-16 00:03:50.003       0.000
  4 2017-07-16 00:04:50.020       0.000
  ...   ... ...
  10032 2017-07-22 23:55:23.803   0.588
  10033 2017-07-22 23:56:23.793   0.580
  10034 2017-07-22 23:57:23.787   0.583
  10035 2017-07-22 23:58:23.797   0.569
  10036 2017-07-22 23:59:23.800   0.549
```

Answer (score 0):

Rule number one in working with data: plot it. The red dots indicate the points where you want to fill in data.

[image: eValue]

The first thing we see is that the beginning 75% of your time series is invalid. I hope you don't want to fill this in some way? If so, don't, and conclusions you will draw from such made-up data will be invalid.

Second, the bunch of dots in the middle of the valid period is also disconcerting. Yes, you will be able to fill that in *somehow*. But the question is really whether the "filled" data will be any use. During this period, you have a big problem.

As to how to fill in such data, you could interpolate linearly: for each invalid data point, pick the last valid data point before, and the first valid point after, then fill with the average of these points. Or more sophisticated: interpolate linearly between these valid points. Or pick not one valid point on both sides, but two or three, and use the average of these points.

Given the major data problems in the middle, you may be better off analyzing or working with your data using a method that can handle invalid data points, rather than trying to fill these in.